# Printer/Copier Device SDK

Tags: sdk, open-source

I have a small project in the office. The project is about extracting data from a Multi-function printer or copier machine to monitor the meter reading. I'm not sure if there is a specific SDK for xerox or other copier machine to integrate an application. Can anyone help me out how to get the SDK or an open source program that I could use for my project.